# Weird Javascript/JQuery Conditional Statement Behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery

I ran across an interesting problem today (Firefox 44). I have a conditional statement that is evaluating the else if statement after evaluating a 'true' if statement. Take an example:

The initial state of `.dataRow` is collapsed. When a dataRow is clicked the first condition is found to be true and the class is changed to expanded. Next the `else if` statement is evaluated and the class is changed back to collapsed because it changed to expanded in the previous condition! **Why in the world would the `else if` statement be evaluated after the first condition is found true?**

```
    $("div").on("click", "div.dataRow", function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass("collapsed"))
    {
        $(this).removeClass("collapsed").addClass("expanded");
    }
    else if($(this).hasClass("expanded"))
    {
        $(this).removeClass("expanded").addClass("collapsed");   
    }
    });
```

I had to put return statements in the conditions to get the function to work properly.

```
    $("div").on("click", "div.dataRow", function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass("collapsed"))
    {
        $(this).removeClass("collapsed").addClass("expanded");
                return false;
    }
    else if($(this).hasClass("expanded"))
    {
        $(this).removeClass("expanded").addClass("collapsed");   
                return false;
    }
    });
```

**EDIT**

Here is a simplified reproduction of the problem [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k0qrbrgj/)

Comment: That might be because of event propagation, cannot comment anything without seeing your html

Comment: No `else` part is evaluated if the `if` statement evaluated to true. Create a MCVE if you think otherwise.

Comment: Maybe you bind event twice and you have html like `<div><div><div class="dataRow"></div></div></div>`

Comment: Can you create a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: @jcubic I think you may be correct. The <div> in question is nested inside another <div>. I am a little confused that I would see this behavior when using firebug and setting breakpoints. I will try to reproduce with fiddle.

Comment: I don't think there's anything to be confused about. You have your event bound to quite the ambiguous element in a `<div>` and you're experiencing a `bubbling up` effect.

Comment: @DrewKennedy I had to use a div because these dataRows are being created dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

I am not into removeClass and addClass of jQuery right now. But each "else if" block condition is evaluated. As you add the class in the first block, the second condition is always true after that.

If you have only two conditions, I would advise you to only use "else". That would protect the second block from being executed, if the first was executed.